# How to overwrite and update data by using websocket in html

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, websocket

I'm a newbie in html and trying to update my data by using Websocket in html. However, I've got stuck at updating my data without pressing refresh button from website... 
It keeps loading when I used console.log(received_msg) from websocket, but it doesn't update data after just once.
How can I overwrite and keep updating data?
I know this might be really stupid question.. 
Should I use while loop or for loop for that or is there any ways to do it?

Here is part of my code in html

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        async: false
    });

var ws = new WebSocket("ws:'my websocket address'"); //just hide my websocket address
    ws.onmessage = function (evt){
        var received_msg = evt.data;
        console.log(received_msg);
        json_parsing = JSON.parse(received_msg);    //updating just once and no updates after that.
        $.each(json_parsing, function(key, val) {
            listStats.push(val);
        });
    }
```

Can anybody help me out here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `json_parsing` variable outside `ws.onmessage` function scope, you need declare it globally:

```
var json_parsing;
var ws = new WebSocket("ws:'my websocket address'");
ws.onmessage = function (evt){
    var received_msg = evt.data;
    json_parsing = JSON.parse(received_msg);
    $.each(json_parsing, function(key, val) {
        listStats.push(val);
    });
}
```

Then `json_parsing` will be accessible for whole document.

Comment: Thank you for replying me back. :) I declared it globally as you said but it still doesn't keep updating the data and show on my web.. Any idea for that?? Thanks.